# Why does "common" come after "diseases" in "diseases common among older people"?

Tags: grammar, adjectives

I have a question about below sentence:

> Diseases common among older people

My problem is why "common" which is an adjective in this sentence has come after the subject "diseases"?

Comment: This is not a complete sentence - there is no verb. Do you have more of it?  Is it a heading?

Comment: It is not the diseases that are common but their occurrence among older people. For example Parkinson's disease is not a common disease generally - 10 million people have it out of 7 billion, but it is commonly suffered by older people.

Comment: Think of it as *diseases (that are) common among older people*.

Comment: @chasly from  UK, Thank you for your reply. this sentence is a title of the lesson from " oxford word skills" book

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adjectival order: “a style appropriate for” or “an appropriate style for”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/453327/adjectival-order-a-style-appropriate-for-or-an-appropriate-style-for)

Answer (score 1):

You can view the noun phrase "diseases common among older people" as containing a form of *elision*, where "which are" or "that are" has been dropped. With this knowledge, you could read it as "diseases (that are) common among older people". This also makes it more apparent how "common" is functioning as an adjective to "diseases".

An example of it in a complete sentence is "several diseases common among older people have recently been discovered to be contributing to alzheimer's disease".

Comment: Good catch. Should I revise that part or just drop it altogether?

Comment: In the 1st para I'd change "clause" to either "expression" or "noun phrase", and I'd drop the first two sentences of the second para. But the final sentence is helpful, so worth keeping. :-)

Comment: @Chappo: So a sentence need not contain a clause?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Strictly speaking, a *complete* sentence must include at least one clause. However, a sentence can also be defined as a meaningful set of words ending in [. or ? or !], in which case if there’s no verb, it can be described as an *incomplete* sentence or a *sentence fragment*.

Comment: @Chappo There, changes made. Went with "noun phrase".